# Common Lisp: Why does lparallel have problems with assigning array elements?

Tags: arrays, concurrency, parallel-processing, common-lisp

I've written a function that copies many elements from one array to another. I wanted to speed it up using the (pdotimes) function from lparallel. The code looks like this:

```
 (pdotimes (i (size output))
   (setf (row-major-aref output i)
     (row-major-aref input (dostuff i))))
```

The (dostuff) function does arithmetic on the row-major output index i to convert it to the row-major input index. When I run this function, the results tend to look like this:

```
#2A((9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 0 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
    (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5))
```

The function is supposed to catenate a matrix of 9s on the left and a matrix of 5s on the right. But notice that there are a few 0s in there too. Zeroes are the initial value for the output matrix, so that means that those elements didn't get assigned.

The non-assignment of elements is seemingly random; run the function many times and zeroes will appear in different places. For some reason, those elements are being missed.

I've tried wrapping the function in a future, like this:

```
(let ((f (future (pdotimes ...))))
  (force f))
```

But that doesn't work either. One thing I've noticed is that the larger the number of threads and the smaller the size of the array, the more elements get missed. It suggests that the array element assignments are clobbering each other somehow.

I've also tried using (pmap-into) to map the function's results into a vector that's displaced to the output, but that fails in a different way: instead of 0s showing up where elements weren't assigned, elements get assigned in the wrong places. If the array contains repeating "1 2 3 4" sub-vectors, sometimes a "1 2 2" sequence will appear, for example.

AFAIK it should be possible for threads to concurrently assign different elements in the same array, but does Common Lisp have problems with this? Do I need to implement a lock so assignments are guaranteed to happen synchronously? If simultaneous assignments were a problem, I'd expect to see more unassigned elements. Any help appreciated.

Edit: I seem to have found how to prevent this, but not the root cause. Try running this in SBCL:

```
(let ((output (make-array '(20 20) :initial-element 0 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 7))))
  (check-type output simple-array)
  (pdotimes (i (array-total-size output) output)
    (setf (row-major-aref output i)
          (random-elt '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))))
```

No zeroes will appear in the output. Now try this in SBCL:

```
(let ((output (make-array '(20 20) :initial-element 0 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 4))))
  (check-type output simple-array)
  (pdotimes (i (array-total-size output) output)
    (setf (row-major-aref output i)
          (random-elt '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))))
```

And see zeroes aplenty. I just tested this with CCL and the output was fine. I'm going to try some other CLs but it seems like this is an SBCL problem so far. For some reason, SBCL has problems doing concurrent assignments to arrays with elements smaller than 7 bits. Character arrays are fine, as are floats and t-type arrays.

Comment: Not surprisingly `(upgraded-array-element-type '(unsigned-byte 4))` is `(unsigned-byte 8)` in CCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly speculative answer, but I'm reasonably sure it's correct.

If an implementation supports arrays whose element size (in bits) is smaller than the smallest object the machine can read from and write to memory, and if it stores those arrays without wasted space (which is, really, the only purpose of having them), then the only approach to updating an array element is:

1. read smallest object containing element from memory;
2. update object with element;
3. write back.

Since writes to different array elements can result in reading and writing the *same* smallest object from memory, this is not safe in the presence of multiple threads without interlocking which would generally have catastrophic performance effects.

Probably all CL implementations have such arrays for modern machines which can't write single bits to memory, in the form of bit arrays.  SBCL also has arrays of element types with 2 and 4 bits, which, assuming machines can read & write no object smaller than 8 bits are also in this area.  It's also possible that arrays with very large object types could suffer from the same problem, if multiple reads & writes are required to load & store an object.

It should be possible to look at the disassembly of code that uses such arrays to see the behaviour.  It's probably also the case that such arrays have lower performance than ones with larger element types (experimentally this is true for SBCL on x64: code which initialises an `(unsigned-byte 4)` array is 2.5 times slower than that which initialises an `(unsigned-byte 8)` array).

---

As a note, I suspect strongly the right approach to getting good performance out of array-bashing code is to partition the arrays amongst the cores in a fairly smart way.

That being said, here's a way to initialize an array of nibbles (`(unsigned-byte 4)`s) which I think should be safe on the assumption that the smallest object that can be written atomically is a byte.  The trick is to write pairs of even-odd addresses at once:

```
(defun initialize-nibble-array (a)
  ;; the idea is to put some pattern in it I can see if it has holes
  (declare (type (array (unsigned-byte 4) *) a))
  (let ((s (array-total-size a)))
    (pdotimes (i (truncate s 2))
      (let ((rmi (* i 2)))
        (setf (row-major-aref a rmi) (mod rmi 8)
              (row-major-aref a (1+ rmi)) (mod (1+ rmi) 8))))
    (when (oddp s)
      ;; if the array has an odd number of elements we've missed one
      ;; at the end
      (setf (row-major-aref a (- s 1)) (mod (- s 1) 8)))
    a))
```

Comment: If you must do parallel assignment to a 4-bit element array, it seems a reasonable approach would be to run the assignments in two synchronous sets; during the first set, only the even indices would be assigned, then during the second set the odd indices would be assigned. This would prevent the same-minimal-memory-object assignment collision you describe and shouldn't be too much slower provided the threads used for the first set of assignments finish at about the same time. For 2-bit elements you'd have to do 4 sets of assignments.

Comment: @phantomics: that's safe but it's a performance disaster.  What a competent FORTRAN compiler would do is unroll the loop so that you do read modify-low-nibble modify-high-nibble write.

Comment: @phantomics: I worked out a safe (I think) way of doing this is to do even-odd pairs in one go.  I added an example which works for me (but I'm finding it hard to make my VM break things probably because it's a VM).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a minimal example as follows (uses *lparallel* and *alexandria*)

```
(let ((output (make-array '(20 20) :initial-element '_)))
  (check-type output simple-array)
  (pdotimes (i (array-total-size output) output)
    (setf (row-major-aref output i)
          (random-elt '(a b c d e f g h)))))
```

And it consistently fills the output grid as follows, each time:

```
#2A((B G C D H A F E D C F D F G D F A C G G)
    (C E D D F A H A F D G E G A C C F G E G)
    (H C A E C F E H E D F G D B H B B A H D)
    (D H G H H A E B G D E G D E G C E A B B)
    (B E H G E E C D A H F A E C F D D A H H)
    (C B D D G D H H D G H C A A H G B G C C)
    (H H D D C F D B H B H G B C F G H F D E)
    (F B C C A H D H G H C D G G D F E G A B)
    (A E G C C H F C F C E F H H D E C H H D)
    (H G H C D F G E D E C E A H C E A H H H)
    (E C B E E C A D B G A F C B G A D G F D)
    (H D D H A E A A G D H B H D A G A G C F)
    (C D F H D G A D E C F C C D F A F F C H)
    (H H D E C B C B E B B G G H H B A A E H)
    (G F C C B F C D D D H F A B C F F C A B)
    (D A H B B F H B B B F F H B G B H C F E)
    (A G H C D H A H C H B F D D A G A E B G)
    (G H A D H G B E A A B F C E G G G D E D)
    (C E G F H F A A A H D D F B F C H B G B)
    (H E H D D F F H E G G A A E D G C H H B))
```

But, [3.6 Traversal Rules and Side Effects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_f.htm)
 says that the consequences are undefined if you modify a fill-pointer (impossible for non-vectors) or adjust the array (?). But your example does not look like the array is being adjusted.

Sorry for the question but does it work with `dotimes`? Does my example work on your machine?

Comment: Interesting, your example works on my system every time. My code works fine with `dotimes` but that's just single-threaded. If you'd like to try my actual code I can post instructions, let me know.

Comment: I think I've figured it out, see above. It has to do with the element type when using SBCL.